# More Resource Intensive: Tampermonkey script (for video control) running on ALL domains—or just 1K domains each with its own @include entry?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I've got a quick question--and I apologize in advance if the answer is (or should be) obvious… the question might betray my very basic [i.e., basically non-existent] fluency in code.

But I wrote a .js userscript in Tampermonkey to allow me to have more precise control over video playback in Safari.  I've had it set to run on all domains:

```
// @include http://*
// @include https://*
```

And while that's certainly worked for me thus far, I'm aware that the script runs needlessly on the 80% of my Internet-ing I do that doesn't involve any interaction with video elements… So I went through and compiled an exhaustive list of ~1,000 specific domains where it makes sense to have the script running, e.g.,:

```
// @include     *://*.facebook.com/*
// @include     *://*.vimeo.com/*
// @include     *://*.youtube.com/*
```

But after actually entering in 1,000 lines of this into my [formerly quite petite!] userscript, it dawned one me that--as far as I know--I could actually be greatly *increasing* the amount of system resources it takes to run this script by forcing it to now run through a long list of domains to see if it matches… and that perhaps simply having it run by default could be less resource-intensive?

Ha, at the same time, I can also imagine how running it everywhere = *obviously* more of a waste of resources… But since I've no idea how I'd even go about testing this (and I certainly don't have a solid enough grasp of the underlying theory here) --> I thought I'd leave it up to the experts, and reach out to you here for advice!

Thank you for your help!!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer because it's too big for a comment and because I don't have the inclination to setup and run some new experiments right now. (If someone posts an answer with updated, verifiable numbers, it gets my upvote.)

Here's a rough sketch of what happens when you have Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, etc. and installed userscripts:

1. **Every page you visit** is checked against the `@include`, `@match`, and `@exclude` directives of **every active userscript**.  The smarter engines would check `@exclude` first and stop if a match is found.

   Some engines are better about this checking than others and, ideally, the site match information would be kept in memory for maximum speed.
2. **Every `<frame>` or iframe on all the pages you visit** are checked against the `@include`, `@match`, and `@exclude` directives of every active userscript, unless that script has `@noframes` set.
3. If a script matches a page (or frame), then Tampermonkey (etc), must:
   (A) Fetch the script code, and any data -- often from disk (slow).
   (B) Then create some level of sandbox -- depending on the engine, the browser, and the `@grant` mode.
   (C) Inject the script into the aforementioned sandbox -- almost always wrapped by an anonymous function -- and run it.
4. Then, the userscript will use resources, depending on its code.

**In general:**

1. `@match` performs better (last checked years ago) than `@include`.  If you are going to use 1000 lines, use `@match` over include.
2. Use `@noframes` unless you have a reason not to.
3. Steps 1 and 2 ideally can be done all from memory (need to see what the various engines currently do), and a *lot* of `@include`s can be processed in the same time it takes to inject one userscript.  (Anybody want to try to collect some numbers?)
4. If a userscript or its data (`@require` files, `@resource` files, `GM_setValue` data) need to be fetched from disk, then that's comparatively a huge time lag. (But still faster than fetching stuff from the internet.)

Finally, the time effort and possible stress of having to **maintain a large list** of sites, editing the userscript file each time, has to be **compared to how invasive your script is**.

If it was me, and the script only delayed pages by less than about 300 milliseconds, I'd just hold my nose and use:

```
// @match    *://*/*
// @noframes
```

However, if the script is more invasive, slower, or more resource intensive, you can use a hybrid approach...
Keep the list of sites to *fully* run on in `GM_setValue` data and/or a `@resource`d file.

That way you could edit the list on the fly using, for example, menu commands; or via the Tampermonkey script-data editor; or even via buttons that you create for that purpose.  All of that is beyond the scope of *this* question, however.